# Operation not permitted, open txt

Tags: node.js

Can anyone please help me with this error? This is node.js.- Discord.js

```
(node:13144) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open '../830717249516994560.txt'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:476:3)
    at Object.writeFileSync (fs.js:1467:35)
    at C:\Alkmaar\commands\close.js:19:28
    at C:\Alkmaar\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4875:16
    at C:\Alkmaar\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4875:16
    at C:\Alkmaar\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:24:16
    at C:\Alkmaar\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4898:21
    at C:\Alkmaar\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4447:11
    at C:\Alkmaar\node_modules\kareem\index.js:136:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:13144) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:13144) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

**ticket.js:**

```
const { Client, Message } = require('discord.js')

module.exports = {
    
    /**
     * @param {Client} client
     * @param {Message} message
     */
    run : async(client, message) => {
        const ch = message.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === message.author.id)
        if(ch) return message.channel.send('Je hebt al een ticket open staan. Klopt dit niet? DM Resul#5375')
        message.guild.channels.create(`${message.author.id}`, {
            type : 'text',
            parent : '807252516080713729',
            permissionOverwrites : [
                {
                    id : message.guild.id,
                    deny : ['VIEW_CHANNEL']
                },
                {
                    id : message.author.id,
                    allow : ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'SEND_MESSAGES', 'ADD_REACTIONS', 'ATTACH_FILES']
                },
                {
                    id : '813062477070729228',
                    deny : ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'SEND_MESSAGES']
                }
            ]
        }).then(async channel=> {
            message.reply(`**Je ticket is aangemaakt!** Zie je geen ticket? DM Resul#5375. Klik op <#${channel.id}> om naar je ticket te gaan.`)
            channel.send(`${message.author}, Het Support Team komt je Zo snel Mogelijk helpen. Zet alvast je vragen/klachten in de ticket. @here`)
        })
    }
}

module.exports.help = {
    name: "ticket"
}
```

close.js:

```
const { Message, Client, MessageAttachment} = require('discord.js')
const fs = require('fs')

module.exports = {
    
    /**
     * @param {Client} client
     * @param {Message} message
     */
    run : async(client, message) => {
        if(message.channel.parentID !== '807252516080713729') return message.channel.send('Je kan dit alleen in een ticket gebruiken!');
        const transcriptChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.get('807287688381857852')
        message.channel.send('Ticket wordt binnen enkele seconden afgesloten.....')
        setTimeout(() => {
            message.channel.delete().then(async ch=> {
                client.ticketTranscript.findOne({ Channel : ch.id }, async(err, data) => {
                    if(err) throw err;
                    if(data) {
                        fs.writeFileSync(`../${ch.id}.txt`, data.Content.join("\n\n"))
                        transcriptChannel.send(`${message.guild.members.cache.get(ch.name).user.username}z'n ticket is gesloten.`)
                        await transcriptChannel.send(new MessageAttachment(fs.createReadStream(`../${ch.id}.txt`)));
                        client.ticketTranscript.findOneAndDelete({ Channel : ch.id })
                    }
                })
            })
        }, 5000)
    }
}

module.exports.help = {
    name: "close"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

fix the absolute path to `830717249516994560.txt` file with :

```
const path = require('path');
....

const filePath = path.join(__dirname,`../${ch.id}.txt`); 
fs.writeFileSync(filePath,data.Content.join("\n\n"));
```

Comment: I dont know what you meaning? I am a beginner.